# unable to store my all retrieve the data from the Mysql table to my new html form.

Tags: php

Here i am facing a problem with the while loop.. (i think) unable to store my all retrieve the data from Mysql table to my html form.

the first row is only getting posted and the rest of the rows are not posting due to same name element getting repeated from the while loop,

Here the $_POST['mechanic_name']; one time i'm using.. any problem with this.. 
because this is not in a while loop, ore if you think any other problems with the code below pls advice

```html
<?php
                  include("db_conection.php");
                  $view_users_query="select * from mechanic";//select query for viewing users.
                  $run=mysqli_query($dbcon,$view_users_query);//here run the sql query.

                  while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($run))//while look to fetch the result and store in a array $row.
                  {
                      $mechanic_ID=$row[0];
                      $mechanic_name=$row[1];
                       
                  ?>

             
                  <tr>                       
                      <td>
                         <input name="mechanic_ID" type="text" value="<?php echo $mechanic_ID;  ?>">    
                      </td>

                      <td>
                      <input name="mechanic_name" type="text" value="<?php echo $mechanic_name;  ?>">  
                      </td>
</tr>


<!--* For save php script*-->

<?php

include("db_conection.php");//make connection here
if(isset($_POST['register']))
{
    $mechanic_ID=$_POST['mechanic_ID'];//here getting result from the post array after submitting the form.
          $mechanic_name=$_POST['mechanic_name'];//same
          $month=$_POST['month'];//same
                   
    
    if($mechanic_name=='')
    {
        //javascript use for input checking
        echo"<script>alert('Please enter the name')</script>";
    exit();//this use if first is not work then other will not show
    }

//insert the user into the database.
$insert_schedule="insert into schedule (mechanic_ID,mechanic_Name,) VALUE ('$mechanic_ID','$mechanic_name'[enter image description here][1])";
  if(mysqli_query($dbcon,$insert_schedule))
    {
        echo"<script>window.open('index.html','_self')</script>";
    }

}
```

plz help me...!`

Answer (score 0):

ok

your text input have same static name 
you shuld give it an array name if you want to save it like :

```
<input type="text" name="mechanic_ID[]" value="first_one" />
<input type="text" name="mechanic_ID[]" value="second_one" />

and when get data

$mechanic_ids = $_POST['mechanic_ID'];
// this give you data in array ('first_one','second_one')

can resume 

foreach($mechanic_ids as $mechanic_id){
// do some thing in this one
}
```

here good example about [arrays form html and php](https://johnrockefeller.net/html-input-forms-sending-in-an-array-in-php/)

Comment: Yes, @Homan Alhaytham, it's good Thanks.. 
But from on value i was echo from one table's Data row 'code' value="<?php echo $mechanic_ID;  ?> so we con't add "first_one"  "second_one"  is it..?  it will load from one table. 

i tested array function with out value="<?php echo $mechanic_ID;  ?> it's working, but i need when retrieve data from a table that data able to store into other table. 
(it's working with Drop Down menu) but i need with a table format

**bold** Here i am echo data from 'mechanic table' and then going to store it into 'schedule table'

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>

      <form role="form" method="post" action="schedule.php">
         <table class="table table table-inverse table-hover">
          <fieldset>
              <div>
                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Username" name="month" type="Month" value="January">
              </div>

            <thead class="thead-inverse">
               <tr>
                <th>Mechanic Id</th>
                <th>Mechanic Name</th>
                <th>Woking Day Selection</th>
                <th>Delete User</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>


                  <?php
                  include("db_conection.php");
                  $view_users_query="select * from mechanic";//select query for viewing users.
                  $run=mysqli_query($dbcon,$view_users_query);//here run the sql query.

                  while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($run))//while look to fetch the result and store in a array $row.
                  {
                      $mechanic_ID=$row[0];
                      $mechanic_name=$row[1];      
                  ?>

                  <tr>                    
                      <td>
                         <input name="mechanic_ID" type="text" value="<?php echo $mechanic_ID;  ?>">    
                      </td>

                      <td>
                      <input name="mechanic_name" type="text" value="<?php echo $mechanic_name;  ?>">  
                      </td>   
                      <td>
                        <div class="weekDays-selector">
                          <input type="checkbox" name="Sun" id="weekday-sun" class="weekday" />
                            <label for="weekday-sun">S</label>

                          <input type="checkbox" name="Mon" id="weekday-mon" class="weekday" />
                            <label for="weekday-mon">M</label>

                          <input type="checkbox"  name="Tue" id="weekday-tue" class="weekday" />
                            <label for="weekday-tue">T</label>

                          <input type="checkbox"  name="Wed" id="weekday-wed" class="weekday" />
                            <label for="weekday-wed">W</label>

                          <input type="checkbox"  name="Thu" id="weekday-thu" class="weekday" />
                            <label for="weekday-thu">T</label>

                          <input type="checkbox"  name="Fri" id="weekday-fri" class="weekday" />
                            <label for="weekday-fri">F</label>

                          <input type="checkbox"  name="Sat" id="weekday-sat" class="weekday" />
                            <label for="weekday-sat">S</label>

                          </div>
                      </td>
                        <td>
                            <!--button-->
                            <input class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" type="submit" value="register" name="register" >
                        </td>
                  </tr>

            </fieldset> 

                  <?php } ?>

                  </table>
          </form>
        </div>


              <?php

include("db_conection.php");//make connection here
if(isset($_POST['register']))
{
    $mechanic_ID=$_POST['mechanic_ID'];//here getting result from the post array after submitting the form.
          $mechanic_name=$_POST['mechanic_name'];//same
          $month=$_POST['month'];//same
          $Sun=$_POST['Sun'];//same
          $Mon=$_POST['Mon'];//same
          $Tue=$_POST['Tue'];//same
          $Wed=$_POST['Wed'];//same
          $Thu=$_POST['Thu'];//same
          $Fri=$_POST['Fri'];//same
          $Sat=$_POST['Sat'];//same

    if($mechanic_name=='')
    {
        //javascript use for input checking
        echo"<script>alert('Please enter the name')</script>";
    exit();//this use if first is not work then other will not show
    }

//insert the user into the database.
$insert_schedule="insert into schedule (mechanic_ID,mechanic_Name,month,Sun,Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri,Sat) VALUE ('$mechanic_ID','$mechanic_name','$month','$Sun','$Mon','$Tue','$Wed','$Thu','$Fri','$Sat')";
  if(mysqli_query($dbcon,$insert_schedule))
    {
        echo"<script>window.open('index.html','_self')</script>";
    }

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the things is mechanic table whole data (mechsanic_ID , Mechanic_name) able to  retrieve, it's showing all the data; because of while loop, But when register it the very first row only able to posted and the rest of the rows are not posting[interface look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOTSS.jpg).